# Migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 UI upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I have migrated database from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. But my UI looks old SP2010, i can see the option [image] as shown in below image. Do i need to go with that option or do I have to try powershell. Which way is recommended. Can some one who has already done this suggest me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go either way, but to automate the process use PowerShell.

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All | Upgrade-SPSite -Unthrottled -VersionUpgrade -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Thanks Trevor. Once I am done with this. What are the best possible ways to implement same UI i had on my SP2010. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You won't get the same UI. You'll want to adjust to the new UI and make any changes based on the new UI. But it's best practice to make minimal to no changes to the UI (e.g. master page editing).